# JOIN Query In MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am going to generate specific information from all the tables in MYSQL. I have 5 tables in my database. I.e.:

1. advertiser

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `advertiser` (   
       `Adv_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
       `Name` char(20) NOT NULL,   
       `F_Name` char(20) NOT NULL,   
       `Address` varchar(40) NOT NULL,   
       `CNIC` int(13) NOT NULL,   
       `Contact` int(11) NOT NULL,   
       `Monthly_fee` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   
       `Region` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   
       `Reg_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   
        PRIMARY KEY (`Adv_id`) 
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. company_information

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `company_information` (
       `Company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `Company_Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       `Company_Contact` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `Company_Address` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`Company_id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
3. advertisement

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `advertisement` (
       `Ads_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `Adv_id_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `Company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `Ads_Title` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       `Ads_Description` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
       `Ads_Image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`Ads_id`),
        KEY `Adv_id` (`Adv_id_id`),
        KEY `Company_id` (`Company_id`),
        CONSTRAINT `Adv_id` FOREIGN KEY (`Adv_id_id`) REFERENCES `advertiser` (`Adv_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT `advertisement_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Company_id`) REFERENCES `company_information` (`Company_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
4. ads_type

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `ads_type` (
       `Ads_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `Advertisement_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `Full_Channel_Ads` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
       `Logo_Ads` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
       `Com_Break_Ads` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`Ads_type_id`),
       KEY `Advertisement_id` (`Advertisement_id`),
       CONSTRAINT `Advertisement_id` FOREIGN KEY (`Advertisement_id`) REFERENCES `advertisement` (`Ads_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
5. ads_date

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `ads_date` (
       `Ads_date_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `Ads_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `Starting_Date` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
       `Expiry_Date` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`Ads_date_id`),
       KEY `Ads_id` (`Ads_id`),
       CONSTRAINT `Ads_id` FOREIGN KEY (`Ads_id`) REFERENCES `advertisement` (`Ads_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```

I want to retrive

- Name, CNIN, and Contact from table Advertiser
- Company_Name from company_information
- Ads_Title from Advertisement
- Starting_Date and Expiry_Date From ads_date.

This Query work well for the above rows :

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ads_date a
    JOIN advertisement ci ON ci.Ads_id = a.Ads_id
    JOIN company_information ar ON ar.Company_id = ci.Company_id
    JOIN advertiser ad ON ad.Adv_id = ci.Advertiser_id
    WHERE Expiry_Date >= CURDATE()
```

**Problem:**
I also want to retrive Advertisement_type from ads_type.
how can I do this with a `JOIN` query? Can any one explain?

Comment: did you consider using sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: is this a website? @PatB

Comment: look at my answer below

Comment: hmmm i don,t know how to use it.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *` in JOIN statements. Instead, list the columns you want in your result set explicitly. For example, `SELECT ad.Name, ar.Company_Name, ci.Ads_Title, ...`

Comment: can i mention it directly. or there is any other method in JOIN Query @OllieJones

Comment: or i use like this.
table1.table1id, table2.table2.id and so on...

Comment: and what if there is two or Three column from one table. can it will be like:
ad.column1.column2

Comment: @OllieJones are you there?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another `join`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ads_date a
JOIN   advertisement ci ON ci.Ads_id = a.Ads_id
JOIN   company_information ar ON ar.Company_id = ci.Company_id
JOIN   advertiser ad ON ad.Adv_id = ci.Advertiser_id
JOIN   ads_type at ON  at.Advertisement_id = ci.Ads_id -- Here
WHERE  Expiry_Date >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: but then this repeat other values too. i don,t want to repeat other value

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ads_date a
    JOIN advertisement ci ON ci.Ads_id = a.Ads_id
    JOIN company_information ar ON ar.Company_id = ci.Company_id
    JOIN advertiser ad ON ad.Adv_id = ci.Advertiser_id

    JOIN ads_type at ON at.Advertisement_id =ci.Ads_id

    WHERE Expiry_Date >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: problem:
trying to get property of non object

Answer (score 0):

Add another join as

```
JOIN   ads_type at ON  at.Advertisement_id = ci.Ads_id
```

Then use `group_by  at.Advertisement_id`  to **avoid repetition.**